# How can I stop people stealing my money?

Tags: hacker-experience

I've been stealing money from people's bank account and bitcoin wallets and it seems really straightforward.

How can I secure my money so the same thing doesn't happen to me?

Comment: I really pity the NSA guy who keeps having to check this site sometimes... :)

Comment: @Shadur The best question titles I've seen yet: How can I DDoS someone? How can I steal money? How can I hack peoples bank accounts? etc.

Answer (score 4):

### Rule #1: ALWAYS. CLEAR. YOUR. LOGS!

Never forget to clear the logs on the servers you connect to and your own log. These contains the information needed to hack you. In your case, delete the logs on your machine and on the bank's server.

### Rule #2: BITCOINS! These are coins! That you cannot feel in your hand..

Bitcoins is a real currency, but the Bitcoins in the game are fake, so you are not actually holding money in your game (which is a good thing, because 1 Bitcoins is worth 380 USD in real life, and the developer would lose all his money. here is a bit what Bitcoin is about. It's important because the game simulates exactly how it works. Bitcoin is a decentralized currency. That means that it is not help by any companies and the data about who hold how many Bitcoins is not stored by one server, but hundreds of thousands of computer all over the world.

**Now, why is it useful in the game?** Well, there are no logs stored on any servers other than your own, so you don't have to connect to a distant server to hide yourself. The fact that there are no servers also mean that other players cannot go to an IP address and do "Hack Account". (Well, you can hack the login server, but I do not know what kind of logs is stored there. if someone could update me on that that would be nice.)

**But there is a risk!** If you forget to clear your log and someone gets your public and private key, it's not safe anymore. You cannot get a new Bitcoins address in the game yet, so if someone hacks into your server, see your connections info in your log and copies it, it's game over. He will be able to use the account like it's his own.

Comment: Do you only need to clear the bank's logs after logging in/hacking an account, or do you also need to clear them after collecting from your hacked database, spending money, etc?

Comment: @mbomb007 ALWAYS clear your log, whatever you do and do so as quickly as possible. That way you'll avoid being hacked.

Comment: I asked about the BANK's log. Re-read my question.

Comment: @mbomb007 I read correctly, don't worry about that. If you want, go ahead and hack the bank server, I don't know if it changed since the last update, but each transfer is logged in the bank log.

Answer (score 2):

So, first off before you start hacking bank accounts you need to log into your bitcoin account and clear your logs right after, if you don't press the "Logout" button, and stay online, you will stay logged into that bitcoin address.

Next, you'll need two accounts, store both of their numbers and bank ip #'s on the notepad for future use, and then decide which one you want to be secure and your account for transferring, when you steal money, quickly send it to the transferring account and be fast to clear your logs (If you send it to another bank the logs will also be on that bank), then since you're logged in to your bitcoin account you can buy bitcoins with the money you just stole and then sell it to your secure account, there will be no trace of this unless you didn't log in to your bitcoin account and clear your logs beforehand.

This is the strategy I used, and as long as your secure account has never been compromised I promise this will work.

Answer (score 0):

heres some tips:

1. NEVER log in to your own account
2. stack a log edit to be ready instantly
3. never transfer between banks, otherwise it will be logged on 3 different servers. yours, the senders and the recievers. if you want to steal money on a 
   different bank create an account there.
4. clear your logs after:

   - Transfer
   - Logon
   - Collect

Clear banks logs after

- Transfer
- Logon
- DDoS (if you DDoS the bank)

  5. and last but not least, save all your money as BTC and/or spread the remainder through seperate bank accounts.